# Is it possible to set host and port in Rmarkdown document with runtime: shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

Say we are working with an `rmarkdown` document with the following yaml (example `runtime: shiny` "app"):

````
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

### Here are two Shiny widgets
```{r echo = FALSE}
selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20)

sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
              min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
```

### ...that build a histogram.

```{r echo = FALSE}
renderPlot({
  hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE,
       breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
       xlab = "Duration (minutes)",
       main = "Geyser eruption duration")

  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
})
```
````

With a regular shiny app we can set the host and port by setting options: `shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(host = '123.45.67.89', port = 1234))`

Is it possible to establish and set a specific `host` and `port` in the YAML? Or somewhere else in the setup?

Answer (score 2):

do this

### option1

```r
rmarkdown::run("test.Rmd", shiny_args = list(host = '123.45.67.89', port = 1234))
```

`test.Rmd` is the name of your doc. make sure your host `123.45.67.89` is valid. Usually is `127.0.0.1` for local testing or don't provide it to use the default.

### option 2

```r
options(shiny.port = 1234)
options(shiny.host = '127.0.0.1')
rmarkdown::run("test.Rmd")
```

Comment: This works and is helpful +1, however, I'm looking for a way to get the same behavior within the `.rmd` file itself. I believe (?) either of these will require me to run these at the console after the file is saved rather than just using the `knit` button with RStudio. Is there any way to pass shiny_args in the YAML or in a setup chunk with `knitr::opts_chunk` or something else?

Comment: not I am aware of. You should submit a feature request to Rstudio then, nothing I can do here.