# Defining shiny.host and shiny.port in flexdashboard

Tags: shiny, flexdashboard

In Shiny App.R one can use this code to set shiny.host and shiny.port (which is handy so that you can bookmark your App page in a browser)

```
options(shiny.host = '127.0.0.1')
options(shiny.port = 2222)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is that possible to do that in `flexdashboard` .Rmd file?

Comment: after set up host and ports, `rmarkdown::run("xx.Rmd")`

Comment: Thanks for the link and answer you provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69257227/is-it-possible-to-set-host-and-port-in-rmarkdown-document-with-runtime-shiny. Conclusion is that you can't do it directly by knitting from within Rmd... But only from outside, eg from console window: `rmarkdown::run("test.Rmd", shiny_args = list(host = '127.0.0.1', port = 2222))`